# Changing front size cropped some of the text out, even tho autosize is true

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the size of the text but it won't autoscale even tho it's sat to true, I've also tried to do it through code but that won't work either, so some of the text is just cropped out...

```
    private void sizeValue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sizeValueObj = sender as NumericUpDown;
        float fontSize = (float)sizeValueObj.Value;
        textLabel.Font = new Font(textLabel.Font.Name, fontSize);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Label, when is expanded in size, isn't overlapped by some other control? What Font are you using? Is the NumericUpDown setup to use 2 decimal places? What is the Text of the Label (what language)?

Comment: @Jimi
Yes, it's not overlapping anything, I'm just using Microsoft sans serif. The NumercUpDown goes up 1 every time. The text of the label is "Example text" and the programming language is c#

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce it in any way (also tested .Net FW 3.5). Make a new project to test just this condition and post a reproducible example.

Comment: The one thing that I haven't tested is the VS IDE setup on a screen with a `dpi != 96` (it turns out I don't have a screen like that here, that's disappointing). If that's the case (you should always work at 96 DPI anyway) and your Form `AutoSizeMode = Font`, change it to `Dpi` and set the Label's Font explicitly (don't let it inherit the Font from the container - the Form here, probably - unless really necessary).

Comment: I mean, with the VS IDE setup with a DPI different from the standard `96`.

Comment: I found out I just had to put autosize = true; before I update front size then I works, Thanks for your help anyway :)